# mysql subquery in select join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a problem with the following statement:

```
SELECT SUM(foreseen_charges.commonCharge) as required, foreseen_charges.flatsId 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT deposits.flatsId FROM deposits GROUP BY flatsId) deps
ON foreseen_charges.flatsId = deps.flatsId
FROM foreseen_charges GROUP BY foreseen_charges.flatsId
```

And I always getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
>   to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT
>   JOIN (SELECT deposits.flatsId FROM deposits GROUP BY flatsId) deps
>       ON f' at line 2

Could anyone help me?

Best Regards,
Cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put *FROM* before *LEFT JOIN*

```
SELECT SUM(foreseen_charges.commonCharge) as required, 
foreseen_charges.flatsId 
FROM foreseen_charges
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT deposits.flatsId 
    FROM deposits 
    GROUP BY flatsId
) deps ON foreseen_charges.flatsId = deps.flatsId
GROUP BY foreseen_charges.flatsId
```

Comment: can you point out why this works to make the answer more useful in general, please.

Comment: @ShawnMehan It's basic Join. I don't think that I should explain why this is works like w3school does.

Comment: well, that's what we do here on SO, help people code better. See @redux for a more generally useful answer that **diminishes** the number of similar questions in the future, assuming other users search and read....sighs....which is a different problem. Despite this, I shan't down vote you but the OP should switch the check to redux answer imho.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing things out of order.  The general structure is:

```
SELECT (something) FROM table JOIN other-table ON table.var1=other-table.var2 WHERE situation
```

You're doing this:

```
SELECT (something) LEFT JOIN table ON table.var1=other-table.var2 FROM other-table
```

You can't join until you've declared both tables, and you can't relate other-table because you haven't declared it yet.

Unsure what the query is meant to accomplish, but this should fix your syntax error:

```
SELECT SUM(foreseen_charges.commonCharge) as required, foreseen_charges.flatsId 
FROM foreseen_charges 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT deposits.flatsId FROM deposits GROUP BY flatsId) deps
ON foreseen_charges.flatsId = deps.flatsId
GROUP BY foreseen_charges.flatsId
```